# Are there separate words for Bananas and Plantains?

Tags: comida

I see the word "Plátano" written above both yellow fruits and green fruits.

En inglés las palabras son "banana" y "plantain"

¿Hay alguna palabra para la distinción entre las dos frutas?

- plátano dulce y amarillo
- plátanos verdes que se comen cocidos?

¿Hay solo un sustantivo en lugar de una frase mucho más larga?

Comment: Relacionado: [Other Spanish synonyms to "Banana"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1129/1674) y ["Plátano" and "banana", geographical differences?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5638/1674).

Comment: https://www.asale.org/damer/plátano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algunos puristas (ejemplo [1](https://www.consumer.es/alimentacion/es-lo-mismo-una-banana-que-un-platano.html), [2](https://www.bmsupermercados.es/platano-o-banana-mejor-los-dos.htm)) distinguen entre **plátanos** y **bananas** en español, y consideran tres clases:

- **Plátano macho:** más verde "harinoso", se usa para cocinar, viene de Ecuador.
- **Banana:** de Senegal, más amarilla
- **Plátano de Canarias:** de Canarias, moteado y más dulce.

Pero en el lenguaje común, al menos en España, se usa **plátano** para todas las clases. La entrada de [banana](https://dle.rae.es/banana?m=form) en el DLE (*Diccionario de la Lengua Española* de la RAE) solo recoge usos en países latinoamericanos con el significado "variedad de plátano".

Comment: Que es "**DLE**"?

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon El "[Diccionario de la Lengua Española](https://dle.rae.es/)" de la RAE.

Answer (score 0):

En Venezuela se llama **cambur** a la variedad dulce que se suele comer cruda, mientras que **plátano** - o **plátano macho** - suele hace referencia al que se cocina, que es más grande.